# Call to implicitly deleted copy constructor of class error

Tags: c++

I have a class that has a member of type std::thread, however, when I want to use this class as a member of another class I always get the error that the constructor of the other class was implicitly deleted because std::thread constructor is deleted.

My class with the std::thread member looks as follows:

```
class VideoSender {
public:
    VideoSender() : encoderThread([]{}) {};

    ~VideoSender(){};

private:
    std::thread encoderThread;
};
```

The other class looks like this:

```
class RemoteCom {
public:
    RemoteCom() : videoSender() {};

    ~RemoteCom(){};

private:
    VideoSender videoSender;
};
```

I was thinking that I already am properly initializing the std::thread class with (here an empty) function. But I still do get this error, so it seems like somewhere there is still a copy constructor called?

I should also add the I can use the VideoSender class directly without errors. This only happens when used as a member of another class.

**Edit**

I then initialize RemoteCom like this:

```
RemoteCom com = RemoteCom();
```

This is really all there is. I reduced it all to this minimal example, the error still exists.

Comment: `it seems like somewhere there is still a copy constructor called?` yes, indeed. The problem lies elsewhere, not in the code you've shown us. Read the compilation error carefuly to detect where.

Comment: `std::thread`s can't be copied, only moved - make a [mcve] and someone may be able to help you to fix that.

Comment: There must be another part of your code where the copy-constructor is called. The compiler should show you exactly where it is if you read the message carefully. (Or copy-paste it in your question so we can assist you)

Comment: Most likely there is a `RemoteCom` object being copied somewhere. Do you pass such object by value to functions as arguments? Do you return such objects by value from any function?

Comment: I edited the question. I only initialize ```RemoteCom``` like shown now. This minimal example gives me this error, that's all there is in my code.

Comment: Replace `RemoteCom com = RemoteCom();` with `RemoteCom com;` Your version requires a copy constructor to exist (even if it would not be called in practice).

Comment: `RemoteCom com = RemoteCom();` is creating a (temporary) `RemoteCom` object, then using copy-initialization to initialize `com`.

Comment: @john Oh yes of course. That explains a lot. I come from a different language and really need to get used to the C++ syntax :D If you post a complete answer I can mark it as accepted.

Comment: I tried to replicate the error but : https://repl.it/repls/SmoggySeashellObservatory#main.cpp  Maybe I'm missing something.

Comment: @AntiqTech Compile with a version below C++17, and add `-fno-elide-constructors`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The syntax

```
RemoteCom com = RemoteCom();
```

requires a copy constructor to exist and to be accessible. This is true even if optimization would eliminate the call to the copy constructor.

Replace with

```
RemoteCom com;
```

which uses the default constructor directly.

Comment: Worth noting that since c++17 `RemoteCom com = RemoteCom();` is perfectly ok (due to the new temporary materialization rules)

Answer (score 2):

Like you have already noticed, `std::thread` is not copiable, which is why your class' implicit copy constructor is deleted. For this declaration the compiler could utilize the move constructor

```
RemoteCom com = RemoteCom();
```

but it cannot, as it is also deleted. [C++ standard section 11.4.5.3 §8](https://eel.is/c++draft/class.copy.ctor#8):

> If the definition of a class X does not explicitly declare a move constructor, a **non-explicit one will be implicitly declared as defaulted if and only if**
>
> - X does not have a user-declared copy constructor,
> - X does not have a user-declared copy assignment operator,
> - X does not have a user-declared move assignment operator, and
> - **X does not have a user-declared destructor.**

As the `VideoSender` requires a user-declared destructor, because the thread has to *joined* before it is destructed, I would just declare the move operations explicitly defaulted:

```
class VideoSender {
public:
    VideoSender() = default;
    ~VideoSender() {
        // a moved thread is not joinable
        if (encoderThread.joinable()) { encoderThread.join(); }
    }

    VideoSender(const VideoSender&) = delete;
    VideoSender& operator=(const VideoSender&) = delete; 
    
    // Move constructor and move assignment operator
    // Transfer ownership of the thread to this object
    VideoSender(VideoSender&&) noexcept = default;
    VideoSender& operator=(VideoSender&&) noexcept = default;

private:
    // Brace initializer
    std::thread encoderThread{ []{} };
};
```

For the `RemoteCom` I would just refer to *the rule of zero* ([C++ Core Guidelines C.20](https://github.com/isocpp/CppCoreGuidelines/blob/master/CppCoreGuidelines.md#Rc-zero)):

```
class RemoteCom {
// Implicitly declared special member functions are all ok
private:
    VideoSender videoSender;
};
```

With the declarations above the following code would compile on `C++14` and `C++11`:

```
#include <utility>

// Move construction (may be elided)
RemoteCom com = FunctionReturningARemoteCom();

// Move assignment operator
com = FunctionReturningARemoteCom();

// Move construction
Remote com2 = std::move(com);
```

With `C++17` things are a little bit different because of something called *guaranteed copy elision*, but that is outside of this answer.